# How to use Yii extension

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have an extension ckeditor which does not have any file containing class that can be intantiated.

It means I cannot import the class like `Yii::import(ext.ckeditor.???)`.

It contains only .md and .js files and some folders also. I am confused what to import from it.

You can download the extension from http://ckeditor.com/download/releases. In that choose version 4.2.

Comment: looks like you are missing extension file. try downloading again.

Comment: i downloaded different versions man and in all, the class file is not there. Then too when I run ckeditor as a different program it works okay. It means nothing is missing from the extension. Figure out some different solution.

Comment: hope you are using http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ckeditor/ and not the ckeditor from its website?

Comment: Salvadore  Aceves has created an extension already that you can use, https://github.com/xalakox/yii-wysiwyg . Instructions in the README file